# Developing an iOS Framework with Swift compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I'm dealing with a recurring problem. I **developed** an **iOS framework** under **Swift 5.1.3 with xCode 11.3.1**.

Several of my customers are developing their application with different versions of Swift than my framework.

`Module compiled with Swift 5.1.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler`

Same problem with a client that is under xCode 11.4 with Swift 5.2 version

Is there a configuration to be set up so that it is no longer dependent on the SWIFT version?

I've heard about **Swift Compatibility** or **Module Stability** but being quite recent, there is not much documentation.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to enable Library evolution mode to make your library compatible with different Swift compiler versions.

The only change you need to do it enable the `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` build setting in Xcode for your framework (make sure to do it both in debug and release modes).

You can read more about it on the [Library evolution](https://swift.org/blog/library-evolution/) Swift page.

Comment: This does not fix the problem.

Comment: @AymanIbrahim are you sure you set your library up correctly? If you enable library evolution correctly, it should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm using aggregate target, it was No, I changed it to YES.

Comment: I change it in the aggregate target and in the main target, now I'm getting Failed to load module ''